# perf mem record <command> does not work as non root user

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, perf

As a non root user, perf mem record  does not work even though I have set `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid` to `-1` and set `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` on `/usr/bin/perf`

```
getcap /usr/bin/perf  
/usr/bin/perf = cap_sys_admin+ep

cat /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid  
-1
```

```
bash$ perf mem record id  
Error:
You may not have permission to collect stats.

Consider tweaking /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid, which controls use of the performance events system by unprivileged users (without CAP_SYS_ADMIN).

The current value is -1:  
  -1: Allow use of (almost) all events by all users  
      Ignore mlock limit after perf_event_mlock_kb without CAP_IPC_LOCK.  
 >= 0: Disallow ftrace function tracepoint by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN  
      Disallow raw tracepoint acess by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN  
 >= 1: Disallow CPU event access by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN  
 >= 2: Disallow kernel profiling by users without CAP_SYS_ADMIN  

To make this setting permanent, edit /etc/sysctl.conf too, e.g.:
       
        kernel.perf_event_paranoid = -1
```

---

I can't figure out why this doesn't work.

Oddly, I don't get the permission error if I run it with an strace.  It seems to work in this case.
(Again, this is as a non root user)

```
strace -f -e perf_event_open perf mem record id
```

Running `perf --debug verbose=2 perf mem record id` shows that the perf_event_open system call is returning errno 13 (EACCES)

The perf_event_open man page says:

> EACCES Returned when the requested event requires CAP_SYS_ADMIN permission (or a more permissive perf_event_paranoid setting).
> Some common cases where an unpriviliged process may encounter this error: attaching to a process owned by a different user;
> monitoring all processes on a given CPU (i.e., specifying the pid argument as -1);
> and not setting exclude_kernel when the paranoid setting requires it.

This is CentOS 7.6.

Comment: Are you running this inside a container? Sounds like it, according to perf_even_open's response. See if this solves your issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/54966080

Comment: No, this is not inside a container.  Thanks for the idea though.